# Алиас для библиотеки

Tags: linux, cmake, msys2

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли добавить алиас для библиотеки которая находиится в системных путях, в моем случае, это `json-c`.

Дело в том что я использую для сборки проекта `MSYS2` и там при помощи пакетного менеджера `pacman` можно установить данную библиотеку, и она автоматически будет искаться при помощи `find_package`, в тоже время, я хочу собрать проект  под линукс *(Debian / Ubuntu /Linux Mint)*, а там при установке пакета `libjson-c-dev` нет файлов `FIND` для `cmake`.

Можно л как-то при помощи `find_library` найти и добавить алиас для данной библиотеки дабы не ломать структуру проекта `CMAKE`?

Comment: можно это сделать и через find_library, но это так себе подход, лучше, конечно, через find_package. И, кстати, при установке обычно формируются config а не find файлы

Answer (score 1):

Если библиотека на CMake, и в ней есть модуль или конфиг, то искать намного проще через `find_package()`, он для того и создавался. В [данном случае](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/tree/master/cmake) при конфигурировании будет сформирован конфиг-файл. Вам нужно только положить путь к инсталлированной библиотеке в `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`:

```
list(PREPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH path/to/libdir)
find_package(lib_name [<version>] [REQUIRED] [COMPONENTS <list of components>])
```

---

Поиск `<Libname>Config.cmake`-файла будет осуществляться по следующим путям:

```
<prefix>/                                                       (W)
<prefix>/(cmake|CMake)/                                         (W)
<prefix>/<name>*/                                               (W)
<prefix>/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/                                 (W)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/                 (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/                       (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/         (U)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/         (W/U)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/               (W/U)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/ (W/U)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Resources/                            (A)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Resources/CMake/                      (A)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Versions/*/Resources/                 (A)
<prefix>/<name>.framework/Versions/*/Resources/CMake/           (A)
<prefix>/<name>.app/Contents/Resources/                         (A)
<prefix>/<name>.app/Contents/Resources/CMake/                   (A)
```

W - Windows; U - UNIX (Linux); A - Apple

---

`<prefix>` - это путь из `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

`<name>` - это имя каталога библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Какая разница как устанавливать? Там поддержка cmake есть, просто собирай с помощью cmake и нужный файл сам станет в системе и с помощью него можно будет делать find_package